# how to call jquery ajax when (not onClick) and fill a client-side var?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I read some examples of jqueryAjax.
All of them showed how to call ajax onClick event and then fill a html element.

However, I want something eles.
I have a client var (`MessageList`). I iterate it on JS and when I get to its end I want to refill it from the server.

I wrote aspx page.
The JS is on its markup. 
On the code behind I wrote a [WebMethod] called "`FillMessages()"` which returns string (Json).

How can I fill `MessageList` with the json returned from this webMethod, only when the client finish iterates the current `MessageList`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var list = [];

    //parses the list
    function parseList(){
       $.each(list, function(index, obj){
            //do something
        });
    }

    //gets the json and class parse (could be added to a seperate function)
    $.getJSON('test.apsx/FillMessages', function(data){
        list = data;
        if(list.length > 0) {
            parseList();
        }
    });

});
```

Don't forget to prepare your webmethod to handle get's by doing decorating them with:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]        
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet =false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: Looks extremely elegant. How can I make a delay between each item parsing? (I want to display them with a delay in between

Comment: Tried to do as you said, but go the following error:GET http://localhost:6578/TB/Display.apsx/RefillMessages 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are you still getting the error? Most of the time it's the little Visual Studio Webserver that needs to be restarted in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

how is the first call being triggered? 
Look at the success handler.

```
function getYouTubeVideoData(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos',
        type : 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        data: {
            v:2,
            'start-index': page*50+1,
            'max-results': 50,
            format:1,
            alt:'jsonc',
            key:'Your API Key',
            q: "Led Zepplin" 
        },
        success : function(response) {
            result_iterator(query, page, response);
            getYouTubeVideoData(page+1);       
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            logger("We had trouble getting data from YouTube..." +  errorThrown);
        }
    })
})
```